# Run C++ program with GMP library to use big numbers cause an error: C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned

Tags: c++, gmp

I'm trying to use this library for a program of big primes.

I had installed GMP and had set a compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

I'm just trying to generate prime numbers:

```
#include <gmp.h>
int main() {
    gmp_randstate_t state;  // variable state for gmp_randinit, must be initialized 
    mpz_t p, q, N;
    mp_bitcnt_t n;  // number of bits for the number in range 0 to (2^n)-1, inclusive.

    n = 10;
    gmp_randinit_default(state);    // Initialize state with a default algorithm.

    while (true)
    {
        mpz_urandomb(p, state, n);  // Generate a uniformly distributed random integer
        if (mpz_probab_prime_p(p, 50) == 2) // Determine whether p is prime. Return 2 if p is definitely prime
            break;
    }
    while (true)
    {
        mpz_urandomb(q, state, n);  // Generate a uniformly distributed random integer
        if (mpz_probab_prime_p(q, 50) == 2) // Determine whether q is prime. Return 2 if q is definitely prime
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run via Visual Studio, I'm getting an error:

```
C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned
```

at the file `gmp.h` line `2230`

When I try to run via WSL 2, Ubuntu with the following:

`g++ filename.cpp -lgmpxx -lgmp`

`./a.out`

I get this output: `Segmentation fault`

I don't understand why is that.

Thanks.

Comment: I have never used `gmp`, but this line may be using an uninitialized variable: `mpz_urandomb(p, state, n);`.  Nowhere do I see where `p` is initialized.  On a pure C++ sense, a parameter that is not initialized that is being sent to a function can only make sense if the function takes a reference parameter, and it seems that `mpz_urandomb` first parameter is not a reference.

Comment: It is a warning, not an error.  If it were an error then you couldn't run the program.  `// must be initialized` is good advice for all of the variables, msvc tries as hard as it can to crash your program when you don't.  Success.

Comment: GMP comes with a C++ wrapper, although support for MSVC is ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C4146 warning is just a bit of Microsoft nonsense. Look it up to understand it, then ignore it. Perfectly correct programs can emit this warning.

The real error in your code (and the cause of the seqmentation fault) is that with GMP `mpz_t` variables must be initialised before use (and destroyed after use).

```
mpz_t p, q, N;
mpz_init(p);
mpz_init(q);
mpz_init(N);

...

mpz_clear(p);
mpz_clear(q);
mpz_clear(N);
```

GMP is a C library not a C++ one, so this kind of manual initialisation is needed.

The GMP manual is pretty good, you should take a look.

Comment: How can I print those numbers?

Comment: You mean to this: https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Formatted-Output.html

Comment: That'll do. I think you can get it as a PDF as well.